# Program Throw Out of Bounds Exception Regardless of Array Size and Iterates Erratically

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop, sum

I'm writing a method that sums two one-dimensional arrays and returns the result in a single array. I then have a test main which accepts or rejects the results but I'm having an issue with my try-catch blocks and the iteration of the loop. I have been unsuccessful in pinpointing the source of these errors. The try catch block is simple:

```
try {

   For (loop that compares arrays named op1 & op2 based on the length of op1) {

}
} catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException) { Console.WriteLine("*****OutOfBounds Exception"); } // Catch out of range exception
```

I have tried using an arrayList in place of a fixed array to solve these issue, as well as basing the loop iteration on a fixed value and the length of op2. Any hints or idea on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Add two binary numbers stored in int arrays: op1 + op2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="op1">Operand #1</param>
        /// <param name="op2">Operand #2</param>
        /// <returns>the sum of op1 and op2</returns>
        public static int[] AddBinary(int[] op1, int[] op2) {
            //ArrayList tempResult = new ArrayList();     // Temporary ArrayList to combine the two arrays. 
            int[] result = new int[4];

         try { 

                for (int i = 0; i <= op1.Length; i++) // Loop through int[] op1 (starts at 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("op1: " + op1[i]);
                    Console.WriteLine("op2: " + op2[i]);


                if (op1[i] < 0 || op2[i] < 0) // Terminate if int[] op1 or int[] opt2 are less than 0. 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Binary digits cannot be less than 0.");
                    //break;

                }

                if (op1[i] > 1 || op2[i] > 1) // Terminate if int[] op1 or int[] opt2 are greater than 1. 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Binary digits cannot be greater than 1.");
                    //break;
                }

                /* 
                 * Handles the carry by assigning the value of 1 to 
                 * opt at I and 0 to op2 in the index value after op1[i]
                 * Should cause overflow
                 */

                if (op1[i] == 1 && op2[i] == 1)
                    {
                        result[i] = 1;
                        result[i++] = 0;
                        //tempResult.Add(op1[i] == 1);
                        //tempResult.Add(op1[i++] == 0);
                    }

                    if (op1[i] == 0 && op2[i] == 0)
                    {
                        result[i] = 0;
                    }


                    // Adds the current value of op1 and op2 into the list

                    /*
                     * assigns the value of 1 to result if op1 is equal to one or 
                     * zero and the opposite is true of op2.
                     */


                    else
                    {
                        //tempResult.Add(op1[i]); 
                        //tempResult.Add(op2[j]);
                        result[i] = 1;


                    }

                }

            } catch (System.IndexOutOfRangeException) { Console.WriteLine("*****OutOfBounds Exception"); } // Catch out of range exception

            Console.WriteLine("Result: ");
            for (int j = 0; j <= 4; j++ )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result[j]);
            } 

            /*
             * Convert Array list to a traditional array for return

            int[] result = (int[])tempResult.ToArray(typeof(int));
            */


            return result;

        }
```

The following are the parameters passed to the method, though not given the main tests the output of the method.

```
                           new TestCase(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, true), //01     // Should cause overflow and throw an exception
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 0 },             new int[] { 1 },             new int[] { 1 },             false),//02
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 0, 1 },          new int[] { 0, 1 },          new int[] { 1, 0 },          false),//03
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 0, 0 },          new int[] { 0, 0 },          new int[] { 0, 0 },          false),//04
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, false),//05
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new int[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, false),//06
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 2 },             new int[] { 1 },             new int[] { 1 },             true), //07        // should detect an invalid char and throw an exception
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, true), //08        // should detect an invalid char and throw an exception
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, false),//09
                            new TestCase(new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, new int[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 }, new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }, false),//10
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem rather than a large amount of code, in incomplete snippets, with commented out sections, poorly formatted.

Comment: (The fact that you're using `index <= array.Length` in two places is probably the root cause though. If an array has length 4, the valid indexes are 0, 1, 2 and 3 - *not* 4.)

Comment: _"The fact that you're using index <= array.Length in two places is probably the root cause"_ ... which you would have probably seen if you had *used a debugger* to step through the code ...

Comment: The arrays are supposed to have five spaces, 0, 1, 2, 3, & 4 and I didn't think using <= in two separated loops would have any negative consequences. They aren't nested unless I made a seriouse bracketing error, also the last for loop is used only to print the contents of the result array. Its completly expendable outside of testing. 

As for the amount of code I gave I apologize, I thought I gave the minimal amount of code needed to debug the code, by no means did I post the entire contents of the program.

Comment: Oh no, you were right, that second for loop is nested.